# How do I create a responsive grid layout like unsplash.com with changing content - React js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, frontend

I am pulling the last 6 posts from facebook. when a new post is posted the content of the grid will change but I would need the layout to still fill out like [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/) at all times.

So far I am looping through the posts

```
{facebook.loading ? <Loading full/> : facebook.data.data.slice(0, 6).map((item, key) => <Col xs={12} md={4} className="feed-body-each" key={`social-key-${key+1}`}>
       <SocialMediaCard
         name={item.from.name}
         logo={'/images/golocal.jpg'}
         image={item.full_picture}
         post={item.message}
         postedOn={moment(item.created_time).format('LL')}
       />
</Col>)}
```

Comment: Show us your code and what you got so far and we can help. But make sure you make it a reduced case

Comment: they are using a masonry layout. for example like this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-component

Comment: Updated with code example @Dominik.

Comment: Thanks @JonasPraem. Will have a look at that now